# Spock and Grails - wait for event to occur from service or controller

Tags: events, grails, asynchronous, spock, geb

I am running a spock test in which I need to wait for an asynchronous event to occur from either a service or controller, and assert that it's contents are true. For example, take the following pseudo-code...

```
def "testA"() {

when:
//start the event
service.startEvent()
//wait for event to complete, and get it's contents
waitFor  { event.complete } 
result << event.eventContents

then:
data == [1,2,3,4]

}
```

My use case is that I am doing a functional test on an emailing feature in my application. I need the application to send the mail, wait for the email to arrive, and assert it's contents are true.

Comment: I tried using the [platform-core plugin](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/events.html) but I couldn't follow the documentation :/

Comment: I might be missing the point, but can't you just use something like [mailinator](http://mailinator.com/)? Send the email to yourTestUser123@mailinator.com, drive to the `yourTestUser123@mailinator.com` inbox on the mailinator website and make some assertions about its content?

Comment: That is a great idea! I use mailgun so it should be totally possible. Though I guess what I am looking for specifically is a way to trigger and wait for events inside Spock. In case I come across anything else in the near future that I cannot simply drive to, I can have a reusable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Java-esque way to do it using a ArrayBlockingQueue.  If someone comes up with a better answer I'll give it to them.

TestSpec.groovy

```
@Shared
def testService = Holders.applicationContext.getBean("testService")

def "testA"() {

    when:
    def result = testService.eventQueue.poll(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    then:
    result == [1,2,3,4]
}
```

TestService.groovy

```
ArrayBlockingQueue eventQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1) //limited to 1 message
```

TestController.groovy

```
def testMessage() {
    def data = [1,2,3,4] //Switch with params and real life appplication
    testDataService.eventQueue.add(data)
    render 'OK'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be sufficient to have a method in the service which just returns whether the mail has arrived? A simple return of `Boolean` should suffice. That method should help you with your wait.

If waiting for events is something you want then perhaps you can raise an enhancement request in Spock with what you think would be a good idea?

Comment: Well I actually need to get the params from the controller in order to complete my assertion. But you're right, it could be much simpler. So I cleaned it up a bit. Thanks for your input